# Java logger problem

Tags: java, logging

I would like to record the logs of my Java application.
I have created this class:

```
public class Log {

    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DigiScope.log");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public Log(String message) {
        try {
            // Create an appending file handler
            boolean append = true;
            FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("my.log", append);

            // Add to the desired logger
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.mycompany");
            logger.addHandler(handler);
            logger.info(message);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

And for each button I have a code like that:

```
private void btnNewPatient ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
Log a = new Log("New Patient created");
}
```

This code creates a log.txt, but records only the click on the first button, the others clicks on the others buttons are not record.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a handler on the other buttons like you do on the first?  Also, is the code in your second block exactly as it is in your source?  That doesn't look like it will compile.

Comment: Are you using `java.util.logging`? Anyway, you should not create and add a handler to the logger each time a button is clicked. You should add the handler once (either by configuration or by code), and have each click log a message using the logger.

Comment: this is not the way the Logging API is intended to be used. You should have a `static final` member field `logger` in your class, call `logger.info` from the action listener, and have a logging.properties which configure the logged messages to go to the file. Is there a good reason not to adhere to this in your case?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make much sense to create a proprietary logging wrapper in your app - java.util.logging is already such a wrapper, so I recommend using it directly. You should create logger objects in your classes, then log messages within handler methods something like this:

```
logger.info("New Patient created");
```

And you should use the same `Logger` instance throughout your class, instead of creating new instances all the time. The standard way is to create one `static final` instance per class.

It is also better to configure logging from a config file, not from code.

I recommend reading through the [Java Logging Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

Péter Török and StriplingWarrior are right with their suggestion to use the Logging framework in the right way:

```
logger.info("New Patient created");
```

instead of creating a new Logger for each statement.

---

But even with your construction, you should have a logfile with all logging information.
For each invocation of the Log constructor, a new `my.log.X` file is created (X is a number). And from this point in time each log statement is logged in this file.

So if you invoke the constructor three times (with message: "first", "second", "third") then you should have the files: my.log, my.log.1. my.log.2

- `my.log`: "first", "second", "third"
- `my.log.1`: "second", "third"
- `my.log.2`: "third"

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it's probably logging each click, but you're reopening the file with each new log message, rather than appending to it.